# FFmpeg - Converting AVI to MP4 (no audio in QuickTime player)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, quicktime, avi

I converted an avi file to a mp4 file with the following command, but the converted mp4 file produced no audio when played with QuickTime (no such problem with other players). I was able to convert mkv to mp4 with the same command without the audio problem.

```
ffmpeg -i show.avi -vcodec libx264 -vprofile high -crf 28 -acodec copy show.mp4
```

However I was able to fix the problem by the following two commands (first extract the audio into a mp3 file from the mp4 file, then combine the mp4 file with the mp3 file).

```
ffmpeg -i show.mp4 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -qscale:a 4 -ar 48000 show.mp3
ffmpeg -i show.mp4 -i show.mp3 show2.mp4
```

show2.mp4 showed no audio problems with QuickTime. Anyone has any ideas as to what was wrong with the first command?

Below is my ffmpeg info.

```
% ffmpeg -i show.avi -vcodec libx264 -vprofile high -crf 28 -acodec copy show.mp4
ffmpeg version N-60236-gffb000fff8-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  \
Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug \
--disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio \
--cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls \
--enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom \
--enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf \
--enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband \
--enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis \
--enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab \
--enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp \
--enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 \
--enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
libavutil      57. 18.100 / 57. 18.100
libavcodec     59. 20.100 / 59. 20.100
libavformat    59. 17.100 / 59. 17.100
libavdevice    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
libavfilter     8. 25.100 /  8. 25.100
libswscale      6.  5.100 /  6.  5.100
libswresample   4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
libpostproc    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
Input #0, avi, from 'show.avi':
  Metadata:
    software        : Nandub v1.0rc2
  Duration: 01:38:52.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 984 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (DIV3 / 0x33564944), yuv420p, \
576x240, 842 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] profile High, level 2.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] 264 - core 164 r3081 19856cc - H.264/MPEG-4 \
AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html \
- options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex \
subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 \
chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 \
fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=7 lookahead_threads=1 \
sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 \
constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 \
direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 \
scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 \
crf=28.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 \
aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'show.mp4':
  Metadata:
    software        : Nandub v1.0rc2
    encoder         : Lavf59.17.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive),\
 576x240, q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 11988 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.20.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.48 bitrate=  \
 0.8kbits/sframe=  120 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     148kB \
time=00:00:05.01 bitrate= 242.5kbits/s speed=21.2x    
video:71kB audio:73kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB \
muxing overhead: 3.456417%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] frame I:1     Avg QP: 9.52  size:    77
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] frame P:65    Avg QP:26.99  size:  1030
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] frame B:54    Avg QP:22.71  size:    92
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] consecutive B-frames: 32.5% 16.7% 17.5% 33.3%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  1.3%  0.1%  P16..4: 13.7%  5.2%  \
4.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:75.4%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  0.2%  0.0%  B16..8:  7.8%  0.4% \
0.0% direct: 0.1%  skip:91.1%  L0:41.8% L1:50.0% BI: 8.2%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] 8x8 transform intra:39.3% inter:58.4%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 8.9% 6.7% 2.4% inter: 5.5% \
4.8% 1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 80%  9% 11%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12% 10% 69%  2%  2%  2%  \
1%  2%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 13% 38%  5%  6%  6%  \
5%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 68% 14% 17%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:27.7% UV:15.4%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] ref P L0: 75.3% 11.5%  8.5%  3.4%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] ref B L0: 83.8% 11.1%  5.1%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] ref B L1: 98.9%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x76824c0] kb/s:115.09
```

Comment: QuickTime is obsolete avoid using it

Comment: instead of qt use ffplay which typically gets installed together with ffmpeg and friends

Comment: @Scott Stensland thanks.  my question is that clearly ffmpeg is able to create a mp4 file that qt can play without problems, so why the avi to mp4 conversion created a different type of mp4.  Just wonder if there're options I can use to fix the problem.

Comment: @Shiping Your FFmpeg log isn't useful, you cut off the part about the input codecs. Anyways it's very possible that your AVI had incompatible codec for MP4 (which accepts MPEG audio like AAC and MP3, but most playback systems expect AAC and might ignore the MP3 codec).

Comment: @VC.One thanks for your comments.  I've added the remaining log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your log I can see that your input audio is MP3.

```
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
```

Most systems expect MPEG container (MP4) to hold AAC audio **as standard**.

- Actual MP4 audio codecs can be AAC, AC3, ALAC, CELP and many others.
- But to keep to one standard, they prefer AAC.
- Using AAC yourself is the safest option for universal playback in most media players.

The fastest fix is **not** to use `-acodec copy` if the input video has non AAC audio.

**Solution:**

```
ffmpeg -i show.avi -vcodec libx264 -vprofile high -crf 28 show.mp4
```

**PS:** 
Regarding `ffmpeg -i show.mp4 -i show.mp3 show2.mp4`. It is not necessary to create a temp MP3 file. Here you are telling FFmpeg to ignore the MP3 inside `show.mp4` and use the MP3 of `show.mp3` which is actually the same thing.

You can achieve same result without middle step of making an MP3 file.

```
ffmpeg -i show.mp4 -c:v copy show2.mp4
```

Where the output `show2.mp4` will now have AAC audio (it is default choice by FFmpeg for MP4 unless you specify a different codec).

Comment: PS: `-c:v copy` achieves same thing as `-vcodec copy`.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.  One question, is it possible to sniff out audio type from the input file with ffmpeg? E.g. to let ffmpeg just print out a line like Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s or a few lines containing audio info.

Comment: >  is it possible to sniff out audio type from the input file with ffmpeg?
you could use [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html) for that